# Lattice of a fuzzy number?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

Can somebody define what is a fuzzy lattice? How to compute lattice of a fuzzy number?

Please try to be generic and basic in the explanation as I'm a beginner in studying fuzzy theory and soft computing.

Comment: 1. Where did you run across the term?  Did it define the term?  If not, can you quote the surrounding context?  2. What research have you done?  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Have you looked first at other fuzzy theories? Do you know fuzzy logic, or fuzzy sets? I would not try to explain lattice theory to anyone who does not know what a set is. BTW, do you know (crisp) lattice theory? Not that I am expert on such issues. I just mean that it is a technical topic and there is probably little room for being basic. And it is ill-advised to try learning combination of concepts that you have not learned first separately.

Comment: Yes I know about the basics of fuzzy theory, fuzzy logic, fuzzy sets, defuzzification etc. I have soft computing as a subject in my college. So there's that. I looked up and found this: http://ailab.chonbuk.ac.kr/class_board/pds1_files/Fuzzy%20Numbers.ppt which had some information but it didn't give the theory behind lattice and couldn't understand the calculation. Maybe with an example one could.